# Solution of linear system doesn't work, in parallel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, iterative-method, petsc, preconditioning

I'm solving $Ax = b$ with PETSc, $A$ sparse and asymmetric.

I'm using BCGS or FGMRES or TFQMR as a solver, and ILU as a preconditioner.
When I use 1 core, everything works as expected. But with 8 cores, no,
I get `-5, KSP_DIVERGED_BREAKDOWN`, or `maximum number of iterations exceeded`.

What could be wrong? I am pretty sure my code is correct.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ILU is not implemented for non-sequential matrices, see [here](https://petsc.org/release/manualpages/PC/PCILU/).